# How to find $a+b$ if i know probability function and $\mathsf E[X]$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

How can I find value $a+b$ if the probability function looks the following way:
$$
p_X(x)=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&ax+b, \: x\in\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}\\
&0, \: \text{otherwise}
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
and $\mathsf E[X] = 2$

Comment: Well, what is $\sum p(n)$?  That and the expectation give you two equations, and you have two unknowns....

Comment: The information in the condition is only type Probability function for a random variable, and mathematical expectation value

Comment: Not sure what you are saying.  You have two unknowns ($a,b$) and you have two bits of information...the probability distribution gives you one and the other comes from the expectation. Write out those conditions in terms of $a,b$ and solve to determine those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Because $p$ is a probability function:
$$\begin{align*}1=\sum p_X(n)&=(a\cdot1+b) + (a\cdot2+b) + (a\cdot3+b) + (a\cdot4+b) + (a\cdot5+b)\\&=15a+5b.\end{align*}$$
Now express that $E[X]=2$:
$$\begin{align*}2&=E[X]\\&=\sum n\cdot p_X(n)\\&=1\cdot(a\cdot1+b) + 2\cdot(a\cdot2+b) + 3\cdot(a\cdot3+b) + 4\cdot(a\cdot4+b) + 5\cdot(a\cdot5+b)\\&=55a+15b.\end{align*}$$
So we have to solve the following system of equations: $$\begin{cases}1=15a+5b\\2=55a+15b\end{cases}$$
The solution is: $$\begin{cases}a=-\frac{1}{10}\\b=\frac{1}{2}.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very match